# What different experiences did Anna and Johan have before they reunite?

Tags: monster

Wolf discovered Anna and Johan in the borderlands and sent them to different orphanages.

1. What experiences did Johan have which Anna did not, apart from Kinderheim 511?
2. When and how did they reunite? Was it entirely the work of the Liebert couple or did Johan play a part?